# React native Web View charts are not working in android

Tags: javascript, charts, react-native, webview, google-visualization

I am struggling with this error from last two days.

I am working on a mobile app which is in react native. In this, i want to show some Google charts in my app with the help of web view.

in ios, everything is working fine and I am getting desired output but somehow it's not working in android.

**React Code** -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

 render() {

 return (
  <WebView
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                source={{uri: 'my url'}}
            />


   );
   }
   }
```

**HTML Code - **

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


 <div id="centerwise_chart" style="width: 100%; height:100%; overflow-x: scroll;" ></div>

 <script type="text/javascript" >


 initEnrollmentChart();


 function initEnrollmentChart() {
   google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['bar']
 });

 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCenterWiseChart);
} 


function drawCenterWiseChart() {
  let graphData = [];
  graphData[0] = ['Centers', 'Achieved Target', 'Actual Target', 'Total 
    Area Target'];
  graphData[1] = ['Center 2', 11, 8, 22];
  graphData[2] = ['Center 3', 10, 2, 21];


  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(graphData);

  var options = {
     chart: {
        title: 'Center Performance',
        subtitle: 'Achieved vs Actual Targets',
     },
    colors: ['#f0ad4e', '#5cb85c', '#3097D1'],
   };

  var chart = new 
 google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('centerwise_chart'));


chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}

</script>
```

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: what is the error message??

Comment: there is no error message. it shows me a white screen